# What is word for lover of live theater?

Tags: single-word-requests, theater

One word for lover of theater or avid fan of attending plays

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do like Theater Enthusiast. I was hoping there was a word similar to bibliophile but I haven't come across any related term yet.

Comment: Hi Robert, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Robert - I, too, would love to know if there is a "bibliophile" equivalent, as I need it right now!  An actor friend asked for permission to include a quote of mine on her website.  Unlike the others providing references (film directors, film producers, actors, etc), I'm just someone who attends.  To my ears, the term "theatre enthusiast" is a dated and dowdy word that reminds me of elderly retirees attending matinee sessions; it may be technically correct, but it's unappealing. The term "theatregoer" (from user tk421 below) is far more contemporary, even if it's more muted in its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theatergoer) defines a **theatergoer** as:

> a person who frequently goes to the theater

There is also the term **theater patron** which can imply someone who also provides financial support or a very loyal theatergoer.  See TheFreeDictionary's definition of [patron](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/patron) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A live theater enthusiast is a possibility. I would not say "patron" because that's just someone who attends a theater. That doesn't make you a live theater fan. Possibilities are live theater-enthusiast, live theater-buff (colloquial) or live theater-fan (more standard).

Comment: "live theater-enthusiast" deviates from the intent of the phrase.  Check your dashes.